# Is there any small, transportable mining hardware able to profit?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic

The place I work is huge and the energy consumption is not a problem. Since I spent 8 hours of my day there, I was thinking to build a crypto mining hardware to take it with me and let it mine.

I don't want to leave it there, so I need it to be in a size that I can take it with me every day.

Noise is not a big problem since the room I have already a few computers that are loud enough.

About budget. I was thinking something less than 700-1k$

Profit?: I don't care to be honest. If I can take back the investment at least, it would be nice. See it as a hobby with some small profit.

I want to experiment with different altcoins and change it from time to time based on the difficulty of the network.

Do you have anything to suggest?

Comment: the time for mining bitcoins with small systems is over. You need very special hardware to do so, and it is not possible in small size. You would have to get a highly sophisticated specialist to develop such a thing, or you dive into the area of Altcoins (need to do a lot of reading), to maybe find something which fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [whattomine.com](https://whattomine.com/) and decide what to mine depending on the hash rate you're able to get out of your machine. Hint: BTC is likely not going to work out for you.

Keep in mind though, not all ASICs can mine all coins. You need to first decide what you want to mine, and then you can start looking for the right hardware.